# MySQL SELECT statement find matching substring in multiple tables over multiple columns

Tags: mysql

Table 1: alpha

Table 2: beta

alpha has a varchar column named: alpha_col_1

alpha has a varchar column named: alpha_col_2

beta has a varchar column named: beta_col_1

```
Table: alpha
=============================================
alpha_col_1            alpha_col_2
---------------------------------------------
384{4},3340{1}      |  L:8949{4}, R:6000{90}
324324{2},3340{6}   |  L:8949{34}, R:6000{94}
384{3},3340{569}    |  L:8949{65}, R:6000{1}
=============================================


Table: beta
================================
beta_col_1
--------------------------------
,4059{32},304{9},910384{2345}
,40439{268},234{6235},910384{23}
,526{56},26365{88},234{90}
================================
```

I need a select statement to check if each number between the brackets {} is unique, spanned across the two tables in the given columns.

From my example above, the select statement should catch {1}, {4}, and {90} as not being unique.

There are hundreds of rows in each table that I need to check against.

I'm not sure why the SELECT statement is eluding me, but it is.

How would I build the proper select query to accomplish this task?

What I have so far is only catching the same {} in it's own row it it's own table, not across all rows and all tables ONLY after supplying a digit to check for between the brackets{}.

Is what I'm trying to do possible or do I need to provide more info?

Comment: Wow! Talk about miss-use of a relational database system! What you're trying to do is a horrible use case for an RDBMS and even if you were able to produce a single SELECT query that would answer your question in the general sense it would probably suffer from performance issues on any data set larger than a trivial example

Comment: This is incredibly hard to do with MySQL. You need to normalize your data.

Comment: This statement would only be queried once (at program startup), which is only done once a day (after columns change).  But yes, I'll concede that normalizing the data needs to be done to make this need a reality.

Comment: Are the patterns always the same or can the number of items vary?

Comment: alpha_col_2 stays pretty much the same (there's only an L: and R:), but the numbers change in them.  The other columns also vary in number, and length.  There could be ,40439{268},234{6235},910384{23},3405{945}, etc...

Comment: However, I'm opting to take the advise of Mike and Barmar to normalize the data and then change the C++ program that needs the data.  This may take me a few weeks to do, but in the long run, it's the best (right) thing to do.

Comment: I'm surprised to see that somebody down-voted this question. Though the use of an RDBMS this way is a bad idea the question itself is not a bad one and I feel it might help other users that might have similar (bad) ideas.